# Gathering results of MPI_SCAN

Tags: mpi, openmpi, prefix-sum

I have this array [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] and i am performing scan operation on that.

I have 3 mpi tasks and each task gets 3 elements then each task calculates its scan and returns result to master task

```
task 0 - [1 2 3] => [1 3 6] 
task 1 - [4 5 6 ] => [4 9 15] 
task 2 - [7 8 9] => [7 15 24]
```

Now task 0 gets all the results [1 3 6] [4 9 15] [7 15 24]

How can I combine these results to produce final scan output?

final scan output of array would be [1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45]

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to implement your own scan operation? Since this is not what `MPI_SCAN` does. It applies the scan operation elementwise over each *i*-th element of the input array stored on each node and the result will be more like:

```
rank 0 - [1 2 3] => [ 1  2  3]
rank 1 - [4 5 6] => [ 5  7  9]
rank 2 - [7 8 9] => [12 15 18]
```

Nevertheless, in order to obtain the result that you want, you should add `6` (the last element from the first scan in task 0) to all elements in the next scans:

```
[ 1  3  6][ 4  9 15][ 7 15 24]
           +6 -------------->
            =
[ 1  3  6][10 15 21][13 21 30]
```

Then you should add `15` (the last element from the scan in task 1 *before* `6` was added) to all elements in the next scans and so forth.

```
[ 1  3  6][10 15 21][13 21 30]
                    +15 ---->
                    =
[ 1  3  6][10 15 21][28 36 45]
```

Alternatively you could add `6` only to the results from the second scan, then add `21` to the results from the third scan and so forth.

Maybe you can find some clever way to do that using MPI operations.

Comment: +1; One could implement the above by using an MPI_Scan on the last elements of the arrays (eg, to get the 6 and 15) and then proceeding as above, but if everything is just going to be sent to processor 0 anyway this is a much better way to do it, as there's no additional communications overhead.