# Using MPI_Scan to implement simple prefix sum

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm going to mastering MPI in this summer. I started to read "An Introduction to Parallel Programming" by Peter Pacheco, and solving its exercise. In one of it's MPI exercise he asked for implementing simple prefix sum with MPI_Scan, but I couldn't implement it with MPI_Scan. I found a solution by using MPI_Scatter, and MPI_Gather. Please help me to find an answer for MPI_Scan.

```
// declaring array and result
// generating random array
MPI_Bcast( &array, n, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Scan(array, result, n, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I'm expecting to have prefix sum in *result* but for some reason it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely not getting prefix *sum* using `MPI_PROD` operation - you should be using `MPI_SUM` operation. Also note that `MPI_Scan` and `MPI_Reduce` work *elementwise* on `array`, e.g.

```
result[i] = array_0[i] op array_1[i] op array_2[i] op ... (i = 0,...,n-1)
```

where `array_0` is the array in process 0, `array_1` is the array in process 1, and so on; `op` is the operation specified by the `MPI_Op` handle, e.g. `MPI_SUM` for `+`, `MPI_PROD` for `*`, and so on.

If you have an array with as many elements as the number of procsses then you first need to perform `MPI_Scatter` with a length of `1` element per process, followed by `MPI_Scan`. For larger arrays, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801154/gathering-results-of-mpi-scan).

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it know. My array should be scattered first and then MPI_Scan will work like MPI_Reduce on each elements of array and the result will be prefix sum.